# how to read ram usage from new versions of free and htop?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, openvz, htop

before I switched to Ubuntu 16.04 64bit server on my VSPes (based on OpenVZ), I used to read the output from `free` and `htop` to analyze the actual RAM usage. Now with 16.04 that comes with the new free and htop [things has changed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770108/what-do-the-changes-in-free-output-from-14-04-to-16-04-mean) and I can't no longer understand how to read it. I thought it was because of the OS version but it also happens on 14.04 with those packages updated. From that link seems like -available- in `free` is the equivalent of the old +/- cached/buffered but this output was 4MB in  +/- cached/buffered under "free", now it's:

```
root@server3:~# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         131072       85884           0       73460       45188        3566
Swap:             0
```

what does that even compared to the old one? On old `free` I had almost 120MB left to use if necessary by other processes (and it was true from what I tested), here it's completely different.

Also on htop I see more ram used than the amount available... uh? It used to be 4/128MB there as well.

[image]

Could these bugs of OpenVZ maybe?

Comment: It would be probably better seen with 'free -m' to see the capacity in MB. Yes, the available is the ammount of memory, which is available to new applications, before swapping strikes.

Comment: Things is on 14.04 with OpevVZ I always had 90% of the RAM free now on 16.04 it's almost always the opposite. And even it shows 0 as available its increase when needed without killing apps or swapping (I don't have any swap). That is very confusing. Either the memory management completely changed or the RAM reporting is f**ked by openvz with new versions of Ubuntu.